# error sending json to v4.0.0/book/flights/seatmaps?mode=seatmaps

Tags: json, spring, api, sabre

When I send test json to seatmap I am getting an error. The API explorer is also returning a 500 error.

method: POST
URL: https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v4.0.0/book/flights/seatmaps?mode=seatmaps

I am passing a valid Bearer token and setting the content-type as application/json

The following JSON is what I am posting:

```
{
  "EnhancedSeatMapRQ": {
    "SeatMapQueryEnhanced": {
      "RequestType": "Payload",
      "Flight": {
        "destination": "SAN",
        "origin": "ATL",
        "DepartureDate": {
          "content": "2017-10-23"
        },
        "ArrivalDate": {
          "content": "2017-10-23"
        },
        "Operating": {
          "carrier": "DL",
          "content": "1692"
        },
        "Marketing": [
          {
            "carrier": "DL",
            "content": "1692"
          }
        ]
      },
      "CabinDefinition": {
        "RBD": "Y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I receive the following error from the API:

```
{
  "status": "NotProcessed",
  "reportingSystem": "RAF",
  "timeStamp": "2017-07-19T12:27:54+00:00",
  "type": "Validation",
  "errorCode": "ERR.RAF.VALIDATION",
  "instance": "raf-darhlc005-9080",
  "message": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.sabre.rest.facade.controller.j2x.RestToSoapController.postRestToSoap(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,boolean) throws java.lang.Throwable"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get that error only when I didn't send anything in the body, when I added a payload I got a successful response (below there's a screenshot of my test using Postman).

[image: Image of test]